# Using the betweenDate operation filter for the SoftLayer Ruby API includes values beyond my endDate

Tags: ruby, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to retrieve the invoices for a single month (beginning of one month and ending at the beginning of the next month).  However, I get results for the first day of the ending month in my result set, which I'm not expecting.

Example, this will return invoices for December 1st:

```
account = SoftLayer::Service.new("...")

billing_invoice_service = softlayer_client.service_named("Billing_Invoice");

  object_filter = SoftLayer::ObjectFilter.new
  object_filter.set_criteria_for_key_path('invoices.createDate',
        'operation' => 'betweenDate',
        'options' => [{
                        'name' => 'startDate',
                        'value' => ["11/01/2015 00:00:00"]
                      },
                      {
                        'name' => 'endDate',
                        'value' => ["12/01/2015 00:00:00"]
                      }
                      ]
                      )

invoices = account.result_limit(0,5000).object_filter(object_filter).object_mask("mask[id,closedDate,createDate]").getInvoices
```

If I run with the below filter I get no results for December 1st:

```
account = SoftLayer::Service.new("...")

billing_invoice_service = softlayer_client.service_named("Billing_Invoice");

  object_filter = SoftLayer::ObjectFilter.new
  object_filter.set_criteria_for_key_path('invoices.createDate',
        'operation' => 'betweenDate',
        'options' => [{
                        'name' => 'startDate',
                        'value' => ["12/01/2015 00:00:00"]
                      },
                      {
                        'name' => 'endDate',
                        'value' => ["12/01/2015 00:00:00"]
                      }
                      ]
                      )

invoices = account.result_limit(0,5000).object_filter(object_filter).object_mask("mask[id,closedDate,createDate]").getInvoices
```

So I'm not sure why I get results for December 1st in my first filter when I specify an ending time of 00:00:00.  Thank you.

Edit: Here is a tail of the results from the first filter above (minus the id):

```
...
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-11-30T21:52:17+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-11-30T21:52:16+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-11-30T23:22:14+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-11-30T23:22:13+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T01:43:59+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T01:43:56+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T01:45:36+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T01:45:34+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:05:20+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:05:16+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:12:22+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:12:22+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:06+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:04+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:07+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:04+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:07+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:05+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:08+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:06+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:07+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:13:06+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:21:34+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:21:32+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:38:12+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T02:38:10+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T03:36:07+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T03:36:06+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T04:09:57+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T04:09:55+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T04:37:45+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T04:37:43+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T06:35:34+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T06:35:33+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T07:00:09+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T07:00:06+05:30"},
 {"closedDate"=>"2015-12-01T08:00:32+05:30",
  "createDate"=>"2015-12-01T08:00:30+05:30"}]
```

Comment: can you post the createDate of the items that you should not be getting in the result?

Comment: Added a snippet of the tail end of the result.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to the timezone, the filter does not take in account your current timezone, it only filters the data stored in the database, when the data is displayed it is converted to your current timezone. I suggest you change your end date value considering the timezone difference between the stored data in softlayer and your current timezone

Comment: If the data I see is converted how do I know how much to offset my time by?  Do you know what timezone SoftLayer stores data in?

Comment: Also, this will impact how I capture the beginning of the month invoices as well.  Now I need to know if the previous month ended on the 31st, 30th, or 28th so I can offset the time.

Comment: You can specify your timezone offset in the dates you give for startDate and endDate. The format looks like this for UTC: 12/01/2015 00:00:00+0000

Comment: if I am not wrong the timezone that Softlayer uses is GMT-06:00, try this: change the timezone of the user that you are using to perform the Ruby request (for that go to the portal Account->Users and edit the user ) once your timezone has been changed try again the request and see if you are getting the same error. If that fixes your issue you will need to get first the time of your user, then convert the timezone to GMt -6:00 in your filters and finally get the invoices. Also try sudorandom's suggestion send the start and endDate specifying your timezone.